# Using Heroku without using the Heroku client

Tags: heroku, client

Is it possible to use heroku without using the heroku client.  Specifically, I guess `heroku create` just uploads my ssh key and adds a git remote.  I would like to do it manually.  Not sure if there is an easy way to do it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `heroku create` doesn't upload your SSH keys.  But `heroku keys:add` does.  You can also add SSH keys through the web: https://api.heroku.com/account/ssh

Comment: By now I did a `heroku create` and it died upload my ssh key.  Your link is one piece to the puzzle, thanks for that. I'm a little bit puzzled, why this is not reachable through the dashboard.  Now the web interface would just need some way to create an app, and show me the git remote for that.

Comment: So maybe if you haven't logged in from the command line then running `heroku create` does the `heroku login` thing.  If uploading your ssh key is dying then you should file a support request with Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible: the Heroku commands hit an API backend at https://api.heroku.com.

However...the API isn't well documented anywhere that I know of. So you might be able to reverse engineer the Heroku gem, but you might not be able to stay current.

EDIT: on Windows the Heroku gem is in C:\Program Files\Heroku\lib\heroku. If you're truly interested you can wander through the Ruby code in there.

Comment: @JamesWard, random question: what do you guys use to generate your docs?

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to avoid doing this as you've no real way of keeping things up to date.  Note though that Heroku do provide libraries you can use to interact with their API, for instance [heroku.rb](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb)

Comment: Keeping things up to date?  I would assume that after I created the app and have my ssh key uploaded, most things happen on the server side on push, no?